# What is the 'observed value' when we are talking about the error term

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, error, population

I understand that the error term is supposed to be the difference between the value produced by the population regression model / function and the actual observed value, but what is this 'actual observed value'? The reason I am confused, is because it is also said that the mean of the error terms is equal to 0 (as the value of Y, for a given value of X, is distributed around the mean value of Y at said given value of X). Wouldn't this mean, however, that we would have multiple observations at a given X value, and so there would not just be one 'actual observed value' at a given X value? If this is so, then what would the error term be if, for example, the value predicted by the population regression model was 10, but there were 5 observations of 5, and 5 observations of 15?

What makes this even more confusing is that if the mean of the error term is assumed to be 0, is this only at a given value of X, because I heard that effectively what you are doing is absorbing the error term into the constant (which makes sense), but given that the number and also variation of observations will be different for each given value of X, won't the mean of the error term change for each given value of X, meaning that the constant in the population regression model would change every time X changed, thus giving us a new population regression line each time (which I have never heard about, at least from anyone else)? Thanks if anyone can actually manage to understand what I have said and answer my question.